# Realm creation sometimes crashes

Tags: swift, realm

To create my realm instance I created a class called Realm Provider. Unfortunately it crashes sometimes in line

```
return realm!
```

Can you see what is wrong and why this happens?

```
class RealmProvider {

    private var realm: Realm?
    private let currentSchemaVersion: UInt64 = 6

    func loadRealm() -> Realm {

        if let realm = self.realm {
            return realm
        }

        migrateRealm()

        if let _ = NSClassFromString("XCTest"){
            realm =  try! Realm(configuration: Realm.Configuration(fileURL: nil, inMemoryIdentifier: "test", syncConfiguration: nil, encryptionKey: nil, readOnly: false, schemaVersion: currentSchemaVersion, migrationBlock: nil, deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded: true, objectTypes: nil))
        } else {
            realm = try! Realm()
        }
        return realm!
    }

    private func migrateRealm() {

        Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(
            schemaVersion: currentSchemaVersion, migrationBlock: { _, oldSchemaVersion in

                if (oldSchemaVersion < self.currentSchemaVersion) {
                    self.purgeRealm()
                }
        })
    }

    private func purgeRealm() {
        logger.warning("deleting realm data...")
        do {
            if let realmUrl = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: realmUrl)
            }
        } catch {
            logger.error("failed deleting realm data")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems like Realm is not created in some reason, try to handle errors when creating Realm with `do catch` to get the exact error message.

Comment: Any suggestion how this error message will be delivered to me as this happens only occasionally? I'm using buddybuild and here the stacktrace is 0 libswiftCore​.dylib 
_TFs16_assertionFailedFTVs12StaticStringSSS_Su5flagsVs6UInt32_Os5Never
1 libswiftCore​.dylib 
swift_unexpectedError_merged
2 libswiftCore​.dylib 
swift_errorInMain

Comment: Try to use `do { .. } catch let error { ... }` and output the error.

Comment: 'catch' block is unreachable because no errors are thrown in 'do' block

Comment: Are there any other error messages in logs? `Realm()` throws an error in case if it couldn't be created. Are you able to reproduce this issue?

Comment: The only stacktrace I have is posted above. In my eyes this doesn't really help. I can not reproduce the app with the debugger attached. The app does location logging in the background: The app awakes - persists the location in realm and sleeps again until the next location update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134979/discussion-between-dmitry-and-netshark1000).